# Wordpress menu on click moving site to the top while using sticky navbar

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In understrap-child theme I made navbar stick to the top of the [page](https://bvelo.pl/). But there's a problem when I open menu on the left. If I'm somewhere else than top of the page and try to open the menu it moves me to the top of the page. How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: The navbar doesn’t stick to the top. At least on mobile…

Comment: I had to remove "sticky-top" class from header. If you add this class to header with id="wrapper-navbar" you can see what I'm writing about.